# Get button position in view while button is in cell

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have a table view that has custom cells. In every cell I have a button. When I click on any button I can get its frame but that frame is in the cell. I want button's position in the self.view is this possible? 
I can get the relative position by getting cell's frame and table's start position but Is there any appropriate way to get any object's position in view?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[button convertPoint: CGPointMake(0,0) toView: self.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the frame and store in CGRect as follows:

CGRect rectVal = [cell.superview convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view];

Let me know if you need more help.